# How to install GPaste?

Tags: software-installation, package-management

[GPaste](https://github.com/Keruspe/GPaste) is quite a sexy pasteboard manager:
[image: gpaste]

What's the preferred way to install this on Elementary? I've seen some old Ubuntu ppa's for it, but nothing up-to-date.  Any solutions that have worked for you?

Comment: I use glipper and have a nice clipboard icon on my panel.. gpaste does look nice though.  Don't forget to add it to auto-start.

Comment: @BhikkhuSubhuti interestingly I was told that `gpaste` is in the default Ubuntu repo, so I'm not sure why it's not just showing up there for us...

Comment: I just did sudo apt install gpaste  and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed gpaste by using the terminal command

```
sudo apt install gpaste
```

Then I ran it using **synapse** which is much better than the slingshot menu
It does not show up in the slingshot menu and...
You can execute it with the command line by typing the following
/usr/lib/gpaste/gpaste/gpaste-ui

Not so elegant.. but it works.

Glipper is better since it works on the panel

Comment: SERIOUSLY! It's not showing up for me. How crazy is that. Going to have to look into what's going on on this systems dpkg system...

Comment: try again.  I just added the command line.  You mean the repo is not showing up?  hmmm I have some ppa, but that would not affect anything.

Comment: I am not sure how you will get it to show up on the panel.  It is meant for gnome panel.  glipper is more functional.